# Associating an index with a query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, backend, b-tree

If there are multiple indexes for a given collection, what determines which index is used  when a query is submitted? Can the query submitter select which index to use? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses a query planner to automatically select an index.

You can view the options considered for a query with the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/#explain) command.

Use [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint--) to force the index to use.